# How to get a button Id in of a clicked button?

Tags: java, android

I have a couple of buttons I want to make a computation on, so I want to get the ID of the particular button clicked so I can perform an operation on.

I have configured the id for all my buttons in my XML file.
I hope i can get help here.

```xml
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity"
     android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
             android:id="@+id/displayCalc"
            android:text="0"></TextView>

          <Button
             android:id="@+id/button_one"
             android:layout_width="70dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="1"
             android:onClick="one"/>

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button_two"
             android:layout_width="70dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="2"
             android:onClick="two"/>

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button_three"
             android:layout_width="70dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="3"
             android:onClick="three"/>

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button_add"
             android:layout_width="70dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="+"
             android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
             android:textSize="18sp"
             android:onClick="calcAdd"/>

     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you are passed your button in the view variable in argument to onClick(View view) call getId() on it

Comment: @TheGoldy can you kidly explain that a bit, I'm completely new to Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined in the XML file for the `Button` with id `button_one` with this attribute:

```
android:onClick="one"
```

that the listener  will be a method named `one`, so all you have to do is create that method inside your activity like this:

```
public void one(View view) {
    <your code goes here>
}
```

If you want to refer to the `Button` inside that method you can do it like this:

```
Button button = (Button) view;
```

and if you want its id:

```
int id = button.getId();
```

So create 4 methods (like the one above) inside your Activity class for all 4 buttons: `one()`, `two()`, `three()` and `calcAdd()`.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a little strange. If I got it correctly you want to know which button is clicked in Java/Kotlin and perform some operation based on buuton id.
If that is what you want:

1. Implement `View.OnClickListener` in your activity or fragment related to this xml.
2. Implement `onCLick(View)` method.
3. Now you can use `when` (kotlin) or `switch` (java) to find the clicked button id.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button_one.setOnClickListener(this)
        button_two.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        when (v.id) {
            R.id.button_one -> {
                //TODO (do something for button with id button_one)
            }
            R.id.button_two -> {
                //TODO (do something for button with id button_two)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

say you're doing something like that

```
Button buttonOne = findViewById(R.id.button_one); //now you have access to the button that is in your layout
buttonOne.setOnClickLister(new View.OnClickListener(){ // i hope you understand anonymous inner class
@Override 
public void onClick(View v){ //now when your button is clicked this method is called 
//and you  passed v in argument which is nothing but your button
//you're passed a View object and not a out of the box button because the 
//View.OnClickListener can be implemented on any view if you want to call button 
//specific method on it you cast it to a button , because you know it is a button 
//inside
v.getId() //gives you the id of your button which you wanted
}
}
```

Tell me there is still some confusion .